# Resign text fields - code reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to reuse code I have for dismissing text fields when the user taps anywhere on the screen. I am trying to follow the single responsibility principle, so it doesn't seem like a good idea to put this functionality in a super class and inherit from it.

Here is what I currently have:

TextFieldResigner.m:

```
@implementation TextFieldResigner

+ (void)autoDismissTextFieldsFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:viewController action:@selector(resignOnTap)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [viewController.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

@end
```

my view controller class:

```
@interface EnrollQuestionsViewController ()

@end

@implementation EnrollQuestionsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [TextFieldResigner autoDismissTextFieldsFromViewController:self];
}

- (void)resignOnTap {
    [_myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

This solution just doesn't feel like it fits together neatly. What is a more correct way to go about trying to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is very error-prone. You are accepting objects of class `UIViewController`, then expecting them to have a custom `resignOnTap` selector.

Incidentally, your `autoDismissTextFieldsFromViewController:` selector is misleading; it is registering `UIGestureRecognizers` to *eventually* automatically dismiss text fields. The name of it suggests that it will itself be dismissing text fields.

Calling `becomeFirstResponder` on an object that returns `YES` from `canBecomeFirstResponder` will automatically have `resignFirstResponder` fire on the previous first responder. You could just put this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)]];
```

and add this to your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
  return YES;
}
```

You will have to watch out when using `UITapGestureRecognizer` to do this work for you. If you have other `UITapGestureRecognizer`s on screen, they could cause your tap to not fire depending on your `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` implementation (if there is one).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately it looks like becomeFirstResponder doesn't force resignFirstResponder.

Comment: If you're already okay with expecting classes to have `resignOnTap`, why not just make a `UIViewController` subclass that all of your other view controllers derive from?

Comment: That's probably what I should do. I already have a UIViewController subclass that all of my view controllers derive from, I was just worried that adding this functionality to it might cause some unforeseen problems in view controllers that don't use this functionality. And I was scared to break the principle that a subclass should want all of its base classes functions.

Comment: Interesting; I just tested it. When I call `becomeFirstResponder` on something, the previous first responder gets its `resignFirstResponder` fired as long as the thing you're calling `becomeFirstResponder` is returning `YES` from `canBecomeFirstResponder`.